# load Xaml dynamically in Windows 8.1 runtime app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a windows 8.1 phone runtime app. I have a file in my assets which has Xaml content in it. When a button is pressed, I want to make the contents of a Stackpanel as defined by the Xaml in the file.

I searched around a bit and found that we can read the Xaml file in a string and pass it to XamlReader class which can then be used to assign a new Xaml to the StackPanel. The method I am referring to is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader) and the code is written below too.

```
string xaml =
"<Ellipse Name=\"EllipseAdded\" Width=\"300.5\" Height=\"200\" 
Fill=\"Red\" \"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"/>";
object ellipse = XamlReader.Load(xaml);

//stackPanelRoot is the visual root of a Page in existing XAML markup already loaded by the appmodel
stackPanelRoot.Children.Add(ellipse as UIElement);

//walk the tree using XLinq result and cast back to a XAML type to set a property on it at runtime
var result = (from item in stackPanelRoot.Children
  where (item is FrameworkElement) 
  && ((FrameworkElement) item).Name == "EllipseAdded"
  select item as FrameworkElement).FirstOrDefault();

((Ellipse) result).Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
```

But **my problem is** that the XamlReader class is not available in Windows 8.1 phone runtime app. I am using Visual Studio 2013. I have found a namespace called [Windows.UI.Xaml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml) which is there in Windows 8.1 phone runtime app.

Can anyone please guide me on how to implement the functionality of loading new Xaml in Windows Phone 8.1 runtime.

Comment: Sadly, it seems that the WinRT runtime isn't able to load XAML dynamically. Being able to convert a xaml string into an object (and therefore executing potentially harmful stuff) is apparently considered as a breach in the WinRT "don't load dynamic code" policy...

Comment: @Eilistraee..So is there any other way to achieve this functionality....what I want to do is have a set of templates and change a particular region of my app depending on the template selected by user

Comment: If it does not exist (yet ?) I would write my own parser. I mean you could do that (not overly complicated, just dynamically parse the XAML entity, its properties and attached properties, and its children) or else change the requirements.

Comment: According to the answer below, it seems to be available on 8.1. It wasn't on 8.It's Good news, I take note, and sorry for the first comment :)

Answer (score 3):

The `XamlReader` is available on both Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight apps and Windows Phone 8.1 Store apps:

- On Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight apps:
  [`System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- On Windows Phone 8.1 Store
  apps: [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader)

Comment: @Olivier...Thanks for that...So I included the namespace...but during runtime, an exception was thrown at XamlReader.load() statement saying "No default namespace has been declared."...Why is that?

Comment: @avinash make sure you declare the xmlns in the root XAML element of the string you load (add the following attribute:  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation")